# Hex Code in batch file to COM port

Tags: batch-file, serial-port, hex

I'm trying to send a long hex-code to a COM-port. When I'm using a software for that (for example "Serial Port Monitor"), it works. The code that I have is doing its job on the COM-port and the control signals work properly.

I want to put those commands in a batch file for easier usage for other users. Sadly I don't know how to modify the "echo"-command to make it send my input as hex-code. If there are any other commands that fit this task better than "echo" then please tell me.

I tried sending the ASCII-chars of the hex-code, but 01 is SOH and so on (STX, ETX and CR too). I don't know how to send those as a single-character either. Tried "^A" for SOH, but the COM-port disregarded the "^" and just read the "A".

I'm still a beginner, so I'm thankful for any advice. Thank you!

Comment: Would `set /P "=hex code here" <NUL >COM1` work?  That avoids sending the trailing \r\n, and is probably more appropriate than `echo` for communicating with hardware.

Comment: You need to send the _binary values_ of such bytes, not the ASCII representation of such values in hex code. For example, the Cntrl-A (^A) character is a byte with the binay value 1. You _may_ generate such values in a Batch file, but is not an easy method. See [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6247) for an introduction on this matter and [this one](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5326) for the solution.

Comment: @rojo so you say that the syntax should look like: set /P "=01 30 41" <NUL >COM3 ? Didn't for me like that. It said syntax error.

Comment: @Aacini I have build my own converter as an application in C++, so I got the binary values of the commands. So with the binary values in hand, how would I send those to the COM-port? With echo or something else?

Comment: If the C++ program may take the values of the bytes in the parameters and output the bytes to Stdout, then the Batch file may execute it and redirect its output to COM port. For example: `theCprog 01 30 41 > COM3`.